# How to run a shell script at the end of an install4j installer on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, install4j

I'm trying to create an installer for my jar using install4j, I was able to launch a batch file for windows installer and launch it at the end of installation, but I'm not able to do so for mac os. I have even tried to do a custom script,but still I'm not able to achieve.

here is the custom code

```
Process proc=null;
if(Util.isMacOS())
{
 String certificatePath = context.getInstallationDirectory()+"/certificates/DCU.cer";
 String commandToRun = "sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain "+certificatePath;
 proc= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToRun);
}

if(proc!=null)
{  
  return true;
}
else 
{
  return false;
}
```

How do I get this to work, Or is there any other way to add a **self signed SSL certificate to mac post installation, using install4j**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a "Run executable or batch file" action to call another executable. Then you can also redirect stderr and see of the command prints an error.

Comment: tried but that did not work, I'm not able to figure if it is something specific to Mac/ Install4j. If I'm trying to the debug_installer.sh script it works. It just does not work when I try to install it through the dmg.